# How to identify and fine tune performance bottleneck on PHP+MySQL app on a dedicated server?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, performance, nginx

**Issue:**

I'm running into performance bottleneck during peak usage hours, while system resource is still readily available.

I'm experiencing slow response from the server for ad serving for 2 hours during peak usage time.

**Background:**

I'm working on a dedicated server running **Revive Adserver PHP+MySQL app** for serving 9 millions impression a day on a dedicated server with the following specs:

```
CPU: AMD 2.3Ghz 8-cores
RAM: 32GB
SSD: 250GB x 2, RAID-1
```

The following illustration are numbers during peak usage hours:

```
load average: 1.18, 0.83, 0.65
load average: 1.00, 0.81, 0.64
load average: 1.23, 0.86, 0.66

             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         31820      15843      15977         79        147      13424
-/+ buffers/cache:       2271      29549 
Swap:         2047        405       1642
```

`netstat -an | grep :80 | wc -l` gives me:

11232

`iotop` gives me less than 10M/s performance, while most of the stats goes to `mysql` processes with write activities

```
Total DISK READ: 0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE: 6.63 M/s
```

A disk performance test gives me `168MB/s` during peak usage hours, which means I should still have lots of room for my SSD performance:

`dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=64k count=16k conv=fdatasync; unlink test`

```
16384+0 records in
16384+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 6.38736 s, 168 MB/s
```

The server is using **Nginx** as reverse proxy for serving static content:

`nginx -v`

`nginx version: nginx/1.9.4`

The server is using **Apache** for FastCGI PHP handler:

`httpd -V`

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
   :
   :
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
```

`php -v`

```
PHP 5.4.45 (cli) (built: Sep  9 2015 14:53:48) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd.
```

MRTG chart is giving me stable result (on a 100 Mbit/s connection), during peak usage hours at:

`44 Mbit/s outgoing throughput`

`3.5 Mbit/s incoming throughput`

From what I can identify, the server workload seems under capacity.

**What I have observed and suspected:**

1. `netstat -an | grep :80 | wc -l` result of `11232` is high, I need to do something about it.
2. MySQL needs to be fine tuned, as Ad serving is constantly doing read/write activities to the database.
3. Could the bottleneck be the number of `php` processes running at a given time or any other limit or cap being set?

From what I've mentioned above, how can I identify and fine tune the performance bottleneck?

I am not sure where to begin.

I can only perform live testing for 2 hours during the peak usage hours.

---

### Update 1:

Excerpt of `httpd.conf`

```
Timeout 60
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 150
KeepAliveTimeout 5

<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    25
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
```

Output of `SHOW VARIABLES;`

```
auto_increment_increment    1
auto_increment_offset   1
autocommit  ON
automatic_sp_privileges ON
back_log    50
basedir /usr
big_tables  OFF
binlog_cache_size   32768
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates OFF
binlog_format   STATEMENT
binlog_stmt_cache_size  32768
bulk_insert_buffer_size 8388608
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
collation_connection    utf8_unicode_ci
collation_database  latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server    latin1_swedish_ci
completion_type NO_CHAIN
concurrent_insert   AUTO
connect_timeout 10
datadir /var/lib/mysql/
date_format %Y-%m-%d
datetime_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
default_storage_engine  InnoDB
default_week_format 0
delay_key_write ON
delayed_insert_limit    100
delayed_insert_timeout  300
delayed_queue_size  1000
div_precision_increment 4
engine_condition_pushdown   ON
error_count 0
event_scheduler OFF
expire_logs_days    0
external_user   
flush   OFF
flush_time  0
foreign_key_checks  ON
ft_boolean_syntax   + -><()~*:""&|
ft_max_word_len 84
ft_min_word_len 4
ft_query_expansion_limit    20
ft_stopword_file    (built-in)
general_log OFF
general_log_file    /var/lib/mysql/adsrv336.log
group_concat_max_len    1024
have_compress   YES
have_crypt  YES
have_csv    YES
have_dynamic_loading    YES
have_geometry   YES
have_innodb YES
have_ndbcluster NO
have_openssl    DISABLED
have_partitioning   YES
have_profiling  YES
have_query_cache    YES
have_rtree_keys YES
have_ssl    DISABLED
have_symlink    DISABLED
hostname    adsrv336.dedicatedhost.com
identity    0
ignore_builtin_innodb   OFF
init_connect    
init_file   
init_slave  
innodb_adaptive_flushing    ON
innodb_adaptive_hash_index  ON
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size 8388608
innodb_autoextend_increment 8
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode    1
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    1
innodb_buffer_pool_size 134217728
innodb_change_buffering all
innodb_checksums    ON
innodb_commit_concurrency   0
innodb_concurrency_tickets  500
innodb_data_file_path   ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir    
innodb_doublewrite  ON
innodb_fast_shutdown    1
innodb_file_format  Antelope
innodb_file_format_check    ON
innodb_file_format_max  Antelope
innodb_file_per_table   OFF
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  1
innodb_flush_method 
innodb_force_load_corrupted OFF
innodb_force_recovery   0
innodb_io_capacity  200
innodb_large_prefix OFF
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size  8388608
innodb_log_file_size    5242880
innodb_log_files_in_group   2
innodb_log_group_home_dir   ./
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct  75
innodb_max_purge_lag    0
innodb_mirrored_log_groups  1
innodb_old_blocks_pct   37
innodb_old_blocks_time  0
innodb_open_files   300
innodb_print_all_deadlocks  OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size 20
innodb_purge_threads    0
innodb_random_read_ahead    OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold 56
innodb_read_io_threads  4
innodb_replication_delay    0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF
innodb_rollback_segments    128
innodb_spin_wait_delay  6
innodb_stats_method nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata    ON
innodb_stats_sample_pages   8
innodb_strict_mode  OFF
innodb_support_xa   ON
innodb_sync_spin_loops  30
innodb_table_locks  ON
innodb_thread_concurrency   0
innodb_thread_sleep_delay   10000
innodb_use_native_aio   ON
innodb_use_sys_malloc   ON
innodb_version  5.5.44
innodb_write_io_threads 4
insert_id   0
interactive_timeout 28800
join_buffer_size    131072
keep_files_on_create    OFF
key_buffer_size 8388608
key_cache_age_threshold 300
key_cache_block_size    1024
key_cache_division_limit    100
large_files_support ON
large_page_size 0
large_pages OFF
last_insert_id  0
lc_messages en_US
lc_messages_dir /usr/share/mysql/
lc_time_names   en_US
license GPL
local_infile    OFF
lock_wait_timeout   31536000
locked_in_memory    OFF
log OFF
log_bin OFF
log_bin_trust_function_creators OFF
log_error   /var/log/mysqld.log
log_output  FILE
log_queries_not_using_indexes   OFF
log_slave_updates   OFF
log_slow_queries    OFF
log_warnings    1
long_query_time 10.000000
low_priority_updates    OFF
lower_case_file_system  OFF
lower_case_table_names  0
max_allowed_packet  1048576
max_binlog_cache_size   18446744073709547520
max_binlog_size 1073741824
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size  18446744073709547520
max_connect_errors  10
max_connections 151
max_delayed_threads 20
max_error_count 64
max_heap_table_size 16777216
max_insert_delayed_threads  20
max_join_size   18446744073709551615
max_length_for_sort_data    1024
max_long_data_size  1048576
max_prepared_stmt_count 16382
max_relay_log_size  0
max_seeks_for_key   18446744073709551615
max_sort_length 1024
max_sp_recursion_depth  0
max_tmp_tables  32
max_user_connections    0
max_write_lock_count    18446744073709551615
metadata_locks_cache_size   1024
min_examined_row_limit  0
multi_range_count   256
myisam_data_pointer_size    6
myisam_max_sort_file_size   9223372036853727232
myisam_mmap_size    18446744073709551615
myisam_recover_options  OFF
myisam_repair_threads   1
myisam_sort_buffer_size 8388608
myisam_stats_method nulls_unequal
myisam_use_mmap OFF
net_buffer_length   16384
net_read_timeout    30
net_retry_count 10
net_write_timeout   60
new OFF
old OFF
old_alter_table OFF
old_passwords   OFF
open_files_limit    1024
optimizer_prune_level   1
optimizer_search_depth  62
optimizer_switch    index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on
performance_schema  OFF
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size   10000
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size    10
performance_schema_max_cond_classes 80
performance_schema_max_cond_instances   1000
performance_schema_max_file_classes 50
performance_schema_max_file_handles 32768
performance_schema_max_file_instances   10000
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes    200
performance_schema_max_mutex_instances  1000000
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes   30
performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances 1000000
performance_schema_max_table_handles    100000
performance_schema_max_table_instances  50000
performance_schema_max_thread_classes   50
performance_schema_max_thread_instances 1000
pid_file    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
plugin_dir  /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/
port    3306
preload_buffer_size 32768
profiling   OFF
profiling_history_size  15
protocol_version    10
proxy_user  
pseudo_slave_mode   OFF
pseudo_thread_id    2107455
query_alloc_block_size  8192
query_cache_limit   1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit    4096
query_cache_size    0
query_cache_type    ON
query_cache_wlock_invalidate    OFF
query_prealloc_size 8192
rand_seed1  0
rand_seed2  0
range_alloc_block_size  4096
read_buffer_size    131072
read_only   OFF
read_rnd_buffer_size    262144
relay_log   
relay_log_index 
relay_log_info_file relay-log.info
relay_log_purge ON
relay_log_recovery  OFF
relay_log_space_limit   0
report_host 
report_password 
report_port 3306
report_user 
rpl_recovery_rank   0
secure_auth OFF
secure_file_priv    
server_id   0
skip_external_locking   ON
skip_name_resolve   OFF
skip_networking OFF
skip_show_database  OFF
slave_compressed_protocol   OFF
slave_exec_mode STRICT
slave_load_tmpdir   /tmp
slave_max_allowed_packet    1073741824
slave_net_timeout   3600
slave_skip_errors   OFF
slave_transaction_retries   10
slave_type_conversions  
slow_launch_time    2
slow_query_log  OFF
slow_query_log_file /var/lib/mysql/adsrv336-slow.log
socket  /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
sort_buffer_size    2097152
sql_auto_is_null    OFF
sql_big_selects ON
sql_big_tables  OFF
sql_buffer_result   OFF
sql_log_bin ON
sql_log_off OFF
sql_low_priority_updates    OFF
sql_max_join_size   18446744073709551615
sql_mode    
sql_notes   ON
sql_quote_show_create   ON
sql_safe_updates    OFF
sql_select_limit    18446744073709551615
sql_slave_skip_counter  0
sql_warnings    OFF
ssl_ca  
ssl_capath  
ssl_cert    
ssl_cipher  
ssl_key 
storage_engine  InnoDB
stored_program_cache    256
sync_binlog 0
sync_frm    ON
sync_master_info    0
sync_relay_log  0
sync_relay_log_info 0
system_time_zone    UTC
table_definition_cache  400
table_open_cache    400
thread_cache_size   0
thread_concurrency  10
thread_handling one-thread-per-connection
thread_stack    262144
thread_statistics   OFF
time_format %H:%i:%s
time_zone   SYSTEM
timed_mutexes   OFF
timestamp   1486188305
tmp_table_size  16777216
tmpdir  /tmp
transaction_alloc_block_size    8192
transaction_prealloc_size   4096
tx_isolation    REPEATABLE-READ
unique_checks   ON
updatable_views_with_limit  YES
userstat    OFF
version 5.5.44-cll-lve
version_comment MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Atomicorp
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os  Linux
wait_timeout    28800
warning_count   0
```

Output of `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`

```
Aborted_clients 2188
Aborted_connects    30745
Binlog_cache_disk_use   0
Binlog_cache_use    0
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use  0
Binlog_stmt_cache_use   0
Bytes_received  336007637149
Bytes_sent  135868200114
Com_admin_commands  2165671522
Com_assign_to_keycache  0
Com_alter_db    0
Com_alter_db_upgrade    0
Com_alter_event 0
Com_alter_function  0
Com_alter_procedure 0
Com_alter_server    0
Com_alter_table 0
Com_alter_tablespace    0
Com_analyze 0
Com_begin   2582
Com_binlog  0
Com_call_procedure  0
Com_change_db   2167726231
Com_change_master   0
Com_check   721
Com_checksum    0
Com_commit  2582
Com_create_db   0
Com_create_event    0
Com_create_function 0
Com_create_index    5174
Com_create_procedure    0
Com_create_server   0
Com_create_table    2587
Com_create_trigger  0
Com_create_udf  0
Com_create_user 0
Com_create_view 0
Com_dealloc_sql 10294
Com_delete  90591
Com_delete_multi    107
Com_do  0
Com_drop_db 0
Com_drop_event  0
Com_drop_function   0
Com_drop_index  0
Com_drop_procedure  0
Com_drop_server 0
Com_drop_table  0
Com_drop_trigger    0
Com_drop_user   0
Com_drop_view   0
Com_empty_query 0
Com_enable_governor 0
Com_enable_governor_reconn  0
Com_enable_governor_lve 0
Com_enable_governor_reconn_lve  0
Com_execute_sql 10294
Com_flush   0
Com_grant   0
Com_ha_close    0
Com_ha_open 0
Com_ha_read 0
Com_help    0
Com_insert  732167877
Com_insert_select   7871
Com_install_plugin  0
Com_kill    0
Com_load    2587
Com_lock_tables 336
Com_lvecmd  0
Com_optimize    0
Com_preload_keys    0
Com_prepare_sql 10294
Com_purge   0
Com_purge_before_date   0
Com_release_savepoint   0
Com_rename_table    0
Com_rename_user 0
Com_repair  0
Com_replace 61
Com_replace_select  0
Com_reset   0
Com_resignal    0
Com_revoke  0
Com_revoke_all  0
Com_rollback    0
Com_rollback_to_savepoint   0
Com_savepoint   0
Com_select  16316658
Com_set_option  4335664028
Com_signal  0
Com_show_authors    0
Com_show_binlog_events  0
Com_show_binlogs    3
Com_show_charsets   0
Com_show_client_statistics  0
Com_show_collations 0
Com_show_contributors   0
Com_show_create_db  321
Com_show_create_event   0
Com_show_create_func    0
Com_show_create_proc    0
Com_show_create_table   39055
Com_show_create_trigger 0
Com_show_databases  965
Com_show_engine_logs    0
Com_show_engine_mutex   0
Com_show_engine_status  0
Com_show_events 0
Com_show_errors 0
Com_show_fields 326814
Com_show_function_status    0
Com_show_grants 3
Com_show_index_statistics   0
Com_show_keys   49105
Com_show_master_status  11
Com_show_open_tables    0
Com_show_plugins    0
Com_show_privileges 0
Com_show_procedure_status   0
Com_show_processlist    5
Com_show_profile    0
Com_show_profiles   0
Com_show_relaylog_events    0
Com_show_slave_hosts    0
Com_show_slave_status   11
Com_show_status 17
Com_show_storage_engines    0
Com_show_table_statistics   0
Com_show_table_status   39590
Com_show_tables 26194
Com_show_thread_statistics  0
Com_show_triggers   38841
Com_show_user_statistics    0
Com_show_variables  2792
Com_show_warnings   0
Com_slave_start 0
Com_slave_stop  0
Com_stmt_close  10294
Com_stmt_execute    10294
Com_stmt_fetch  0
Com_stmt_prepare    10294
Com_stmt_reprepare  0
Com_stmt_reset  0
Com_stmt_send_long_data 0
Com_truncate    2587
Com_uninstall_plugin    0
Com_unlock_tables   336
Com_update  44026
Com_update_multi    5124
Com_xa_commit   0
Com_xa_end  0
Com_xa_prepare  0
Com_xa_recover  0
Com_xa_rollback 0
Com_xa_start    0
Compression OFF
Connections 2107678
Created_tmp_disk_tables 2899422
Created_tmp_files   6
Created_tmp_tables  3078901
Delayed_errors  0
Delayed_insert_threads  0
Delayed_writes  0
Enable_governor 0
Flush_commands  1
Handler_commit  748577022
Handler_delete  5716734
Handler_discover    0
Handler_prepare 0
Handler_read_first  377473
Handler_read_key    1100551034
Handler_read_last   57
Handler_read_next   403408954
Handler_read_prev   437
Handler_read_rnd    11287933
Handler_read_rnd_next   261237848
Handler_rollback    84
Handler_savepoint   0
Handler_savepoint_rollback  0
Handler_update  790681045
Handler_write   781433379
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data   7724
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data   126550016
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty  594
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty  9732096
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed    91473015
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free   3
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc   465
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total  8192
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead   2767609
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   57329
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests    12257284809
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads    27826982
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free    0
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests   4117902862
Innodb_data_fsyncs  570895897
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs  1
Innodb_data_pending_reads   0
Innodb_data_pending_writes  0
Innodb_data_read    501890338816
Innodb_data_reads   30632828
Innodb_data_writes  655956295
Innodb_data_written 3482707620864
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written  91473015
Innodb_dblwr_writes 7099319
Innodb_have_atomic_builtins ON
Innodb_log_waits    0
Innodb_log_write_requests   396703814
Innodb_log_writes   555866212
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs    556959782
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs    1
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes    0
Innodb_os_log_written   484844787200
Innodb_page_size    16384
Innodb_pages_created    155964
Innodb_pages_read   30632831
Innodb_pages_written    91473015
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits   0
Innodb_row_lock_time    7629691
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    79
Innodb_row_lock_time_max    141020
Innodb_row_lock_waits   96421
Innodb_rows_deleted 5716233
Innodb_rows_inserted    26794984
Innodb_rows_read    1809037295
Innodb_rows_updated 726405176
Innodb_truncated_status_writes  0
Key_blocks_not_flushed  0
Key_blocks_unused   6679
Key_blocks_used 563
Key_read_requests   7690348
Key_reads   3306
Key_write_requests  5070367
Key_writes  501
Last_query_cost 0.000000
Max_used_connections    113
Not_flushed_delayed_rows    0
Open_files  201
Open_streams    0
Open_table_definitions  400
Open_tables 400
Opened_files    11858607
Opened_table_definitions    78012
Opened_tables   151658
Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_file_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_handles_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_locker_lost  0
Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_table_handles_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost    0
Prepared_stmt_count 0
Qcache_free_blocks  0
Qcache_free_memory  0
Qcache_hits 0
Qcache_inserts  0
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0
Qcache_not_cached   0
Qcache_queries_in_cache 0
Qcache_total_blocks 0
Queries 9420404640
Questions   7254733117
Rpl_status  AUTH_MASTER
Select_full_join    23575
Select_full_range_join  1007
Select_range    2816388
Select_range_check  0
Select_scan 3328035
Slave_heartbeat_period  0.000
Slave_open_temp_tables  0
Slave_received_heartbeats   0
Slave_retried_transactions  0
Slave_running   OFF
Slow_launch_threads 0
Slow_queries    36162
Sort_merge_passes   0
Sort_range  13900
Sort_rows   26363706
Sort_scan   44854
Ssl_accept_renegotiates 0
Ssl_accepts 0
Ssl_callback_cache_hits 0
Ssl_cipher  
Ssl_cipher_list 
Ssl_client_connects 0
Ssl_connect_renegotiates    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_depth    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_mode 0
Ssl_default_timeout 0
Ssl_finished_accepts    0
Ssl_finished_connects   0
Ssl_session_cache_hits  0
Ssl_session_cache_misses    0
Ssl_session_cache_mode  NONE
Ssl_session_cache_overflows 0
Ssl_session_cache_size  0
Ssl_session_cache_timeouts  0
Ssl_sessions_reused 0
Ssl_used_session_cache_entries  0
Ssl_verify_depth    0
Ssl_verify_mode 0
Ssl_version 
Table_locks_immediate   788956379
Table_locks_waited  0
Tc_log_max_pages_used   0
Tc_log_page_size    0
Tc_log_page_waits   0
Threads_cached  0
Threads_connected   8
Threads_created 2107677
Threads_running 2
Uptime  9223463
Uptime_since_flush_status   9223463
```

---

### Update 2:

Here are some addition info showing the current `memcached` stats.  Not sure if it indicates any bottleneck related issue:

```
STAT pid 2032
STAT uptime 9253771
STAT time 1486219189
STAT version 1.4.24
STAT libevent 1.4.13-stable
STAT pointer_size 64
STAT rusage_user 15108.811111
STAT rusage_system 62027.906324
STAT curr_connections 7
STAT total_connections 1999851
STAT connection_structures 108
STAT reserved_fds 20
STAT cmd_get 2195755075
STAT cmd_set 19730696
STAT cmd_flush 73
STAT cmd_touch 0
STAT get_hits 2185756795
STAT get_misses 9998280
STAT delete_misses 0
STAT delete_hits 0
STAT incr_misses 0
STAT incr_hits 0
STAT decr_misses 0
STAT decr_hits 0
STAT cas_misses 0
STAT cas_hits 0
STAT cas_badval 0
STAT touch_hits 0
STAT touch_misses 0
STAT auth_cmds 0
STAT auth_errors 0
STAT bytes_read 206042443758
STAT bytes_written 11178528686414
STAT limit_maxbytes 536870912
STAT accepting_conns 1
STAT listen_disabled_num 0
STAT threads 4
STAT conn_yields 0
STAT hash_power_level 16
STAT hash_bytes 524288
STAT hash_is_expanding 0
STAT malloc_fails 0
STAT bytes 3683296
STAT curr_items 766
STAT total_items 9902981
STAT expired_unfetched 226228
STAT evicted_unfetched 0
STAT evictions 0
STAT reclaimed 1201893
STAT crawler_reclaimed 0
STAT crawler_items_checked 0
STAT lrutail_reflocked 16
END
```

---

**Update 3:**

During peak hours in another day, I'm getting:

```
> netstat -an | grep :80 | wc -l
11281

load average: 2.46, 1.96, 1.83

> free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         31820      14713      17107         80        149      12342
-/+ buffers/cache:       2220      29600 
Swap:         2047        403       1644
```

In addition, here's the excerpt of fcgid.conf

```
FcgidIPCDir /var/run/mod_fcgid/sock
FcgidProcessTableFile /var/run/mod_fcgid/fcgid_shm

FcgidIdleTimeout 40
FcgidProcessLifeTime 30
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 100000
FcgidMaxProcesses 16
FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 4
FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
FcgidConnectTimeout 60
FcgidIOTimeout 1000
FcgidInitialEnv RAILS_ENV production
FcgidIdleScanInterval 20
```

Bandwidth usage is at:

```
36 Mbit/s outgoing
3 Mbit/s incoming
```

Again, seems like there's still lots of free resource available.

With the updated `Fcgid*` directives, the ads on a single page is taking 8~10 seconds to load.

During off peak hours, ads serving usually take less than a second to at most 1.5 second to load.

Also, according to `phpMyAdmin`, the largest two tables are `3.6GiB` and `2.8GiB` in the database, which should theoretically fit in the `32GB` RAM on my server.

I also notice that in my server monitoring stats, the CPU processes are constantly fixed at `500` sleeping process.  See the following for the 1 week interval chart.  Could this be an issue too?

[image]

Here's also the full server health snapshot at peak usage hours.

[image]

How can I find out if there's any OS related limit that's putting a cap on the performance?

eg. active connection, file descriptor, mysql related, php, or httpd process, etc.

---

### Update 4:

Here are the bandwidth chart for the past 7 days.

The issue mentioned above was happening for 2~3 hours during peak hours around middle of the day.

[image]

---

### Update 5:

After adjusting `MaxClients 64` and also tried `MaxClients 20`, the result doesn't change much, it's still taking me 5~10+ seconds to server the ads.

```
> netstat -an | grep :80 | wc -l
11310
```

I tried adding `innodb_buffer_pool_size=16G` to `/etc/my.cnf`, after restarting `mysqld`, and now `SHOW VARIABLES;` gives me

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size 17179869184
```

`top` command shows:

```
8517 mysql     20   0 18.4g 1.3g 7264 S 31.2  4.2   1:33.18 mysqld
```

But still the ad response is taking 5-10 seconds to load, the status bar of the browser always shows, `waiting for domain-name.com...` for over 10 seconds when there's problem.

One thing that I notice.

Whenever I restarted the Apache, everything is responsive for 10 seconds, ad serving was instant within 0.5 seconds in the first 10 seconds after apache restart.

After that, it slows down again.

Which makes me wonder if Apache or PHP is the cause of blocking the connection when there is too many concurrent connection.

Here's my current `my.cnf`, `httpd.conf`, `fcgid.conf`:

*my.cnf*

```
[mysqld]
bind-address=127.0.0.1
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
symbolic-links=0

innodb_buffer_pool_size=16G
query_cache_type = OFF
thread_cache_size = 20

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

*httpd.conf*

```
Timeout 60
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 150
KeepAliveTimeout 5

<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    25
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit  256
MaxClients   64
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
```

*fcgid.conf*

```
FcgidIdleTimeout 40
FcgidProcessLifeTime 30
FcgidMaxProcesses 1000
FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 100
FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
FcgidConnectTimeout 60
FcgidIOTimeout 1000
FcgidInitialEnv RAILS_ENV production
FcgidIdleScanInterval 20
```

---

### UPDATE 6

Following is the excerpt of `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` result update using the above configurations in **Update 5**

```
Aborted_clients 4
Aborted_connects    291
Connections 25804
Max_used_connections    17
Opened_files    121295
Opened_table_definitions    1032
Opened_tables   1481
Threads_cached  11
Threads_connected   6
Threads_created 17
Threads_running 1
```

Looking at the `Opened_files` it seems high to me.

Could that be the cause of locking up the system?

---

### Update 7:

Bandwidth Zoom-in Chart, 5-min Avg

[image]

---

### Update 8 (temporary solution):

I've tried most of the options during the past few days during peak hours, none of them actually help resolve the problem.

The only temporary solution for me is to set a `cronjob` to do a graceful restart of httpd every 30 seconds during the problematic hours.

I'm planning to get another server setup with Nginx + PHP-FPM 7.1 + Percona 5.7 to test the situation.

If I come up with a working solution, I'll post the update here.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is more of a question for serverfault, so it might get downvoted.

Comment: I find that the performance issue is more app service and configuration related, while hardware tuning is of little relevance here, hence I asked the question here at stackoverflow.

Comment: Did you try to use nginx instead of apache? It would be interesting to compare.

Comment: I would have switched to nginx + php-fpm 7.1 instead of apache, but at this moment it's not easy for me to do the switch on a live production server.

Comment: @Farkie, KDX -- One could also argue that this belongs in dba.stackexchange.  A 3-way gray area?  The conundrum is that the Asker does not necessarily know whether the answer lies in hardware, configuration, or even adding an index to a table.  I often see "CPU is high; help me with configuration tuning" -- but the real problem is in the SQL or Schema.

Comment: @KDX, can you zoom in to a bad hour for the network bandwidth graph?  "30-minute avg" is too coarse.  Can you get "1-minute avg" or tighter?

Comment: @RickJames, see **Update 7**, my MRTG chart only gives "5-min avg" graph, can't get anything closer.  The problematic hours is between 10~12.  Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

44Mbs / 100Mbs -- that is nearly saturated.  ~60/100 is all that Ethernet can handle.  I suspect you had spikes that high.

So, either increase the bandwidth on that machine, or add another server running everything but MySQL.

Are your ads stored in MySQL?  Or do you store only a link to the ad, and the ad server has the html?  I ask, because in the former case, you will need more than one extra ad server, and you may need multiple Slaves to deliver the traffic.  (This is since the bulky ads would go across the network from MySQL(s) to the separate ad server(s).)

In any case, you should be working *now* on scaling out both the web server and MySQL.

What is MySQL's `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Max_used_connections';`?  If that is more than say. 30, then MySQL may be stumbling over itself.  When any server (web or database) tries to "too many" things at once, the resources are evenly shared.  This leads to stagnated *throughput* and severe lengthening of *latency*.  When this happens, you are better off throttling things at the highest level practical -- no use starting yet another process if it is just going to bog things down even more.  11232 sounds like such a situation?

The load average sounds like CPU is not a problem.  (It rarely is for MySQL.)

**Analysis of VARIABLES and STATUS**

**Observations:**

Version: 5.5.44-cll-lve
31.1 GB of RAM
Uptime = 106d 18:04:23
You are not running on Windows.
Running 64-bit version
You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) InnoDB.
115 computed Variables/Status/Expressions; interesting ones discussed below

**The More Important Issues**

- You are using less than 1% of RAM for InnoDB's buffer_pool.  Raise `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 16G.  This should cut back significantly on I/O.  However, since your dataset seems to be rather small, it may not help that much.
- `innodb_log_file_size = 90M` -- Currently you have the 'tiny' default of 5M.  90M would decrease certain things that slow things down.  However...  It is not easy to change that setting, especially in 5.5.  So, leave this as a 'last resort'.  (You should plan on upgrading at some point.)
- Half of tmp tables are spilling to disk.  1/5th are doing full table scans.  Let's see some of the slow queries; they can probably be improved -- either by schema changes, query changes, and/or index changes.  This may be the most important toward improving the latency.
- 79 writes/second.  What are you writing?  Can they be batched in some way?
- Lower `long_query_time` to `2`; it will help you find the slow queries.  And set `slow_query_log = ON`.
- Changing database a thousand times per connection (235 times/second)?  What is going on?
- `Thread_cache_size` is now 0; change to 20.  "0" causes each new connection to go through a somewhat lengthy process of establishing a process, etc.  With more than 0, this process is avoided.  This *may* be another significant improvement.
- `max_connections = 151` -- I have already discussed decreasing the need for this at the client.  (No need to change this number.)
- `query_cache_type = OFF` -- to avoid some overhead

**Details and other observations**

`( innodb_buffer_pool_size / _ram ) = 128M / 33393370726.4 = 0.40%` -- % of RAM used for InnoDB buffer_pool

`( open_files_limit ) = 1,024` -- ulimit -n
-- To allow more files, change ulimit or /etc/security/limits.conf or in sysctl.conf (kern.maxfiles & kern.maxfilesperproc) or something else (OS dependent)

`( Innodb_log_writes ) = 555,866,212 / 9223463 = 60 /sec`

`( Innodb_os_log_written / (Uptime / 3600) / innodb_log_files_in_group / innodb_log_file_size ) = 484,844,787,200 / (9223463 / 3600) / 2 / 5M = 18` -- Ratio

`( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written ) = 9,223,463 / 60 * 5M / 484844787200 = 1.66` -- Minutes between InnoDB log rotations Beginning with 5.6.8, this can be changed dynamically; be sure to also change my.cnf.
-- (The recommendation of 60 minutes between rotations is somewhat arbitrary.) Adjust innodb_log_file_size.

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables / (Created_tmp_disk_tables + Created_tmp_tables) ) = 2,899,422 / (2899422 + 3078901) = 48.5%` -- Percent of temp tables that spilled to disk
-- maybe increase tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size; avoid blobs, etc.

`( Select_scan / Com_select ) = 3,328,035 / 16316658 = 20.4%` -- % of selects doing full table scan. (May be fooled by Stored Routines.)
-- Add indexes / optimize queries

`( Com_insert + Com_delete + Com_delete_multi + Com_replace + Com_update + Com_update_multi ) = (732167877 + 90591 + 107 + 61 + 44026 + 5124) / 9223463 = 79 /sec` -- writes/sec
-- 50 writes/sec + log flushes will probably max out I/O write capacity of normal drives

`( long_query_time ) = 10.000000 = 10` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query. 
-- Suggest 2

`( Com_change_db / Connections ) = 2,167,726,231 / 2107678 = 1,028` -- Database switches per connection 
-- (minor) Consider using "db.table" syntax

`( Com_change_db ) = 2,167,726,231 / 9223463 = 235 /sec` -- Probably comes from USE statements.
-- Consider connecting with DB, using db.tbl syntax, eliminating spurious USE statements, etc.

`( Threads_created / Connections ) = 2,107,677 / 2107678 = 100.0%` -- Rapidity of process creation 
-- Increase thread_cache_size (non-Windows)

`Com_create_index` = 2 /HR -- What's going on?  Once per *week* is a high frequency for `CREATE INDEX` !

`have_symlink` and `local_infile` may be security holes.

You have the Query Cache half-off. You should set both query_cache_type = OFF and query_cache_size = 0 . There is (according to a rumor) a 'bug' in the QC code that leaves some code on unless you turn off both of those settings.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135057/discussion-on-answer-by-rick-james-how-to-identify-and-fine-tune-performance-bot).

Answer (score 0):

@KDX A significant factor could be your `innodb_log_buffer_size=8388608` and your `innodb_log_file_size=5242880` which is smaller and not practical.  This link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_buffer_size  shows `innodb_log_file_size of over 50M`.  This could alleviate some of your troubles.  Change your .ini/.cnf shutdown/restart when possible.  Guidelines for this operation from 5.5 refman should be followed.